# Show that if $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are i.i.d., then two expectations are equal.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ i.i.d random variables. Put $S_n:= \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$.

Show that $\mathbb{E}[X_1 I_{\{S_n \in A\}}]= \mathbb{E}[X_j I_{\{S_n \in A\}}]$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$, where $A$ is an arbitrary Borel set.

A possible idea of mine was to prove that the random vectors $(X_1, S_n)$ and $(X_j, S_n)$ have the same joint distribution. The statement intuitively looks obvious because the sum $S_n$  is symmetric in all variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$ so it shouldn't matter which variable we write on the front.

How can I formally show this? (Fubini and all these theorems like are allowed). These things are always hard to show yet seem so intuitive.

Comment: What is $A$ ?...

Comment: Consider $A=\mathbb R$. Why should $E(X_1)=E(X_j)$ hold? This has nothing to do with the independence assumption.

Comment: An arbitrary Borel set.

Comment: But then it's false... unless the variables are not only independent but iid.

Comment: The question says i.i.d though.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta It was just edited. And not the title

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The i.i.d. random variables have this property:  Let $\pi$ be any permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.  Then the two vectors
$$
(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)\qquad \text{and}\qquad (X_{\pi(1)},X_{\pi(2)},\dots,X_{\pi(n)})
$$
have the same joint distribution.  This is called [exchangeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables).  See that wiki site for more information.

Comment: Can you clarify how this helps? I am sorry but I don't see it. Note that there is an indicator function which I don't know how to deal with.

Comment: Let $\pi$ be a permutation that just swaps $1,j$. Let $f(x_1,...,x_n) = x_1 1_{[\sum_k x_k \in A]}$. Then since $X, X \circ \pi$ have the same distribution, so will $Ef(X)$ and $Ef(X \circ \pi)$, if you will excuse the abuse of notation.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.